# contents of xp cd is not visible

Tags: ubuntu, data-cd

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. I want to take an ISO copy of XP installation CD but when I insert CD it's seen as empty CD. Is there any way to access the content of CD?

Comment: How did you check the CD? Could you post the output of `mount` (browse to the CD directory first if using a GUI file viewer)?

Comment: @Graeme
I use Thunar file manager, on the left pane it lists drives and my XP CD seen as `Blank CD-R Disk`

Comment: Can you post the output of `udisks --show-info /dev/cdrom | grep blank`, this is another way to test for a blank CD.

Comment: `udisks --show-info /dev/cdrom | grep blank
    blank:                     1
`

Comment: By the way some suggested running `sudo modprobe sr_mod` but I think that module is not builtin my kernel. I get `sudo modprobe sr_mod
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:505 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file: could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/3.8.0-35-generic/modules.builtin.bin'` error

Comment: Does the drive work ok with other disks?

Comment: Yes, it works ok with other CDs and DVDs. I also added `sudo addgroup $USER disk
 sudo addgroup $USER cdrom`

Comment: `wodim --devices
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.`

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with the disk, is it a copy?

Comment: Open a disc burning application (K3B or the like) and try to write something to the CD. If that works, the CD was really empty. If not, tell us what K3B says.

Comment: If you can't get the disc to work, there are (by all indications) official downloads of Windows ISOs. Microsoft do not appear to link them on their site, but they do not refute the many claims that they are official on their forums (plus the Windows XP ones are on their site). Copyright is not an issue as long as you have a valid product key. See - http://deny120025.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/file-iso-windows-xp-vista-7-and-8/

Comment: @Graeme
Thank you for the link, you are really helpful. As to my question I thought I was not able to see the contents because of an original CD protection. I think it's scratchy, CDs are more liable getting scratchy than DVDs

Comment: The drive is usually a factor as well. If you spend enough $$$ and get good enough quality, it can often read discs others can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have posted, this sounds more like a hardware issue than a software one. It is likely that the drive isn't reading the disc because either the CD is dirty/scratched, the lens in the drive is dirty and/or the drive is near the end of its life. For the drive, you would tend to first notice issues with copied and/or scratched discs.

Another possibility for a copied disc is that there was an error when burning (or it simply wasn't formatted correctly).

Either way, I would suggest trying the disc in another drive. If it reads ok, at least you can rule out that it is completely corrupted.

Otherwise you could try:

- Clean the disc - ideally with something made of soft cotton.
- Clean the drive lens - ideally *gently* with a soft cotton bud and iso-propyl alcohol, although this may require dismantling the drive. You can get lens cleaning kits, though often they aren't that effective.

Answer (score 0):

If `/dev/sr0` is your CD-ROM device, you can use `dd if=/dev/sr0 of=./XP.iso` to make a local copy.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I already tried that with no luck. I get following output `dd if=/dev/sr0 of=./XP.iso
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000210851 s, 0.0 kB/s`

Answer (score 0):

depending to the comments above:

On automounter you won´t see errors. Try to mount it manually on shell.

The command on ubuntu should be

```
sudo mount /dev/yourdevice /your/destination
```

And see if it prints some errors.

But: If dd was not able to find anything your cd, it is really unreadable, so they are too many scratches on it. Try to clean it up and test it again. If it doesn´t, try to download Windows XP related to your version on CD. So, your key should work on this download. You can also try ddrescue. In this case, because CD´s are only readable, you may use ddrescue direct (remember first using dd for nearly broken hdd´s and then ddrescue on the mirrored file(s)).

Comment: None of this will work if the disc registers as blank. The drive needs to register that there is data on the disc before any of it is available via the device file.

Comment: Good point about downloading Windows XP though - there actually seem to be official sources for this.